# How to change the font of a control element in Wix Version 4

Tags: visual-studio, text, wix, windows-installer, wix4

I am trying to change the font size of a Control element by making the text bigger and bolder for my Wix Installer UI using version 4.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="10" Y="20" Width="430" Height="40" Text="!(loc.CustomizeDlg_Title)" />
```

in my localization file:

```
    <String Id="CustomizeDlg_Title" Value="Welcome" />
```

Please let me know how to change the font size, the color of the text and how to make it bolder using Wix version 4.